# Swift correct use of getters and setters

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Can someone please help me understand the correct use of getters and setters in swift. I get the impression its not the same as say Java.

Is this the correct usage in Swift to store and access a class variable?

```
class Person {
    private var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func setName(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about "stored properties" in the Swift documentation ...

Comment: Sure, let's just get rid of this crappy SO site, and people can actually read the doco  :)

Comment: Mike, basically use `didSet` and `didGet`.  Swift is moving away from complicated concepts like properties, getters, etc etc.  This is part of the general trend - if you are staggeringly old like over 95, you'll remember having to do " memory management " and stuff. It's only app development, it's not real programming. It's one step up from doing html (or css, or whatever that's called now). Go with the flow and adopt each new trivial paradigm Apple offers.  `didSet` and `didGet` are your friends here.

Comment: @JoeBlow "It's only app development, it's not real programming." ?? i'm curious about what REAL programming is

Comment: Dude embedded for beer brewing machines.

Comment: @JoeBlow I can't find any mention of a didGet observer. Do you have documentation mentioning it?

Comment: hey @trekkieyk - that's willSet.  sorry for kidding around BTW  :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Swift provides a much more structured approach to `getters` and `setters` than Java.

You can, but you should **not**, write setters and getters as you did in your code.

Instead (if you are using `stored properties`) just declare the property with a visibility non `private` (e.g. `internal` in my example). This way callers outside of your class will be able to see the property and change it.

```
class Person {
    
    var name: String {
        willSet(newValue) {
            print("\(self.name) is going to be renamed as \(newValue)")
        }
        didSet(oldValue) {
            print("\(oldValue) has been renamed as \(self.name)")
        }
    }
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

### Ok but in java getter and setters do allow me to add custom logic to be executed before or after the value is changed.

Right! In Swift, you can do this using the `willSet` and `didSet` observers.

### willSet(newValue)

You write here the code you want to run **before** a new value is written in the property.
Here you can access the current value (that is going to be overwritten) with `self.name` while the new value is available with `newValue`.

### didSet(oldValue)

You write here the code you want to run **after** a new value is written in the property.
Here you can access the old value (that has been overwritten) with `oldValue` while the new value is available in `self.name`.

Both `willSet` and `didSet` are optional [I am **not** talking about Optional Type! I mean you are not forced to write them :)].

If you don't need to run some code just `before` or `after` the property has been changed, just omit them.

### Example

```
let aVerySmartPerson = Person(name: "Walter White")
aVerySmartPerson.name = "Heisenberg"

// > Walter White is going to be renamed as Heisenberg
// > Walter White has been renamed as Heisenberg
```

Comment: Great answer. I think one use case is missed: In Java, one of the points of writing getter/setter methods is so that you decouple your object's interface from its storage (an implementation detail). E.g. you could have a class that stores a temp in F, and has a  `getTempF()` getter, and a `getTempC()` method that derives C a value from the stored F value. If you decide to join the sensible part of the world and use C, then your storage is decoupled from the interface, allowing you to reimplement  `getTempC()` as a mere getter, and `getTempF()` as a method to do a conversion from C to F.

Comment: In Swift, that use case is covered by the fact that instance variables are never exposed as an object's interface (they literally **can't** be). A computed property generates the same sort of getters/setters as a stored property, so changing a property between being stored  or computed is a non-interface-breaking change. Simple!

Answer (score 3):

If you assign to self., you will just be calling this method again. Also, there is no "get" like the old Java bean property pattern. Finally, if you actually need to use methods for property computation or actions after setting, they can be built right into the variable definition.

```
class Person
{
    private var name: String;

    init( name: String )
    {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

should be sufficient for your simple case, although you can also

```
private var name: String {
    didSet {
        // updating something after setting
    }
};
```

Comment: I want to re-set it later though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how setter and getter works as in Java:

```
class Person {
    private var _name
    private var _age
    // .... other properties

    var name: String {
        get {
            return _name
        }
        set {
            _name = newValue
        }
    }

    var age: String {
        get {
            return _age
        }
        set {
            _age = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have seen code where there is only the getter and the keyword `get` is omitted. Where is that documented?