# Error in count Object Array

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
var activeCalculators = Calculators()

func numberOfCalculators()->Int{
        let activeCalculatorsArray = activeCalculators.calculators
        return activeCalculatorsArray!.count
    }


struct Calculators
{
    var calculators: [Calculator]?
    var activeCalculator: Int = -1
    var activeSummary: Bool = false
    var activeProfits: Bool = false

    public func getCalculators()-> [Calculator]
    {
        return calculators!
    }

    public mutating func setCalculators(calculators: [Calculator])
    {
        self.calculators = calculators
    }

    public func  getActiveCalculatorIndex()-> Int
    {
        return activeCalculator
    }

    public mutating func  setActiveCalculatorIndex( activeCalculator: Int)
    {
        self.activeCalculator = activeCalculator
    }

    public func  isActiveProfits()-> Bool
    {
        return activeProfits
    }

    public mutating func  setActiveProfits( activeProfits: Bool)
    {
        self.activeProfits = activeProfits
    }



    public func  isActiveSummary()-> Bool
    {
        return activeSummary
    }

    public mutating func setActiveSummary(activeSummary: Bool)
    {
        self.activeSummary = activeSummary
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
print("XXXXXXXXXXXX: \(numberOfCalculators())")

}
```

When i run my function:   numberOfCalculators() i have error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm trying add this func to my class:

```
public func countCalculators()->Int{
        return (calculators?.count)!
    }
```

but them I have error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

How can you fix it?

Comment: you never called setCalculators that is why it is nill

Comment: Do you have a Java background?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `-1` as a default or sentinel value. Swift has optionals, `Int?` can be `nil`. Take advantage of that. It'll keep you from accidentally indexing into an array with `-1` and crashing your program.

Comment: You do not need, and should not write, manual getter and setter functions to wrap your stored properties. Stored properties *already* synthesize a backing instance variable, and the getter/setter functions that are implicitly used anytime you read/write to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006746/3141234

Comment: Generally, it's simpler to use an empty array over a `nil` optional array. Does that fit your data model well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, unwrap it properly :

```
func numberOfCalculators()->Int{
    return activeCalculatorsArray?.count ?? 0
}

public func countCalculators()->Int {
    return calculators?.count ?? 0 // Suggested by Alexander
}
```

Then you need to `set something before calling get`. So in `viewDidLoad` instead of calling `numberOfCalculators()` call `setCalculators()` first so that you will have some value for calculator.

Comment: `calculators?.count ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided it seems that perhaps `calculators` is nil at the time of your reading. You may want to do some checks it see in your `getCalculators` method...

```
guard let calcs = self.calculators else {
    print("No calculcators!")
    return [] // returns empty (no crash)
}

return calcs // return values
```

In the meantime, it would be nice to investigate why you don't have any calculators in the first place.