# Can I make my own getters and setters and should I?

Tags: swift, setter, getter

Should I make my own getters and setters in Swift? Im confused by the built in getters ad setters...is this even needed?

```
    //properties for the resident
    private var name: String!
    var apartmentNumber: String!
    var email : String!
    var phoneNumber : String!


    public func getName()->String{
        return self.name
    }

    public func setName(name : String){
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: Related (if not duplicate:) [Swift correct use of getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999741/swift-correct-use-of-getters-and-setters).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written [an article for exactly this](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md). I'll paste it here.

---

## Stop writing getters and setters in Swift

I see this time and time again, and it's about time I write an article in one place to consolidate all my thoughts. If you find yourself writing code that looks like this, listen up:

```
public class C {
    private var _i: Int = 0
    public var i: Int {
        get {
            return self._i
        }
        set {
            self._i = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern* *is completely pointless* in Swift, and I'll explain why, but firstly we need to take a short detour through Java land. Why Java? Because most of the people I run into who write Swift like this have some sort of Java background, either

1. because it was taught in their computer sceince courses, or
2. because they're coming over to iOS development, from Android

### What's the point of getters and setters?

Suppose we have the following class in Java:

```
public class WeatherReport {
    public String cityName;
    public double temperatureF;

    public WeatherReport(String cityName, double temperatureF) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.temperatureF = temperatureF;
    }
}
```

If you showed this class to any CS prof, they're surely going to bark at you for breaking encapsulation. But what does that really mean? Well, imagine how a class like this would be used. Someone would write some code that looks something like this:

```
WeatherReport weatherReport = weatherAPI.fetchWeatherReport();
weatherDisplayUI.updateTemperatureF(weatherReport.temperatureF);
```

Now suppose you wanted to upgrade your class to store data in a more sensible temperature unit (beating the imperial system dead horse, am I funny yet?) like Celcius or Kelvin. What happens when you update your class to look like this:

```
public class WeatherReport {
    public String cityName;
    public double temperatureC;

    public WeatherReport(String cityName, double temperatureC) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.temperatureC = temperatureC;
    }
}
```

You've changed the implementation details of your `WeatherReport` class, but you've also made an API breaking change. Because `temperatureF` was public, it was part of this class' API. Now that you've removed it, you're going to cause compilation errors in every consumer that depended on the exitense of the `temperatureF` instance variable.

Even worse, you've changed the semantics of the second double argument of your constructor, which *won't* cause compilation errors, but behavioural errors at runtime (as people's old Farenheit based values are attemped to be used as if they were celcius values). However, that's not an issue I'll be discussing in this article.

The issue here is that consumers of this class will be strongly coupled to the implementation details of your class. To fix this, you introduce a layer of seperation between your implementation details and your interface. Suppose the Farenheit version of our class was implemented like so:

```
public class WeatherReport {
    private String cityName;
    private double temperatureF;

    public WeatherReport(String cityName, double temperatureF) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.temperatureF = temperatureF;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return this.cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public double getTemperatureF() {
        return this.temperatureF;
    }

    public void setTemperatureF(double temperatureF) {
        this.temperatureF = temperatureF;
    }
}
```

The getters and setters are really basic methods that access or update our instance variables. Notice how this time, our instance variables are `private`, and only our getters and setters are `public`. A consumer would use this code, as so:

```
WeatherReport weatherReport = weatherAPI.fetchWeatherReport();
weatherDisplayUI.updateTemperatureF(weatherReport.getTemperatureF());
```

This time, when we make the upgrade to celcius, we have the freedom to change our instance variables, and tweak our class to keep it backwards compatible:

```
public class WeatherReport {
    private String cityName;
    private double temperatureC;

    public WeatherReport(String cityName, double getTemperatureC) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.temperatureC = temperatureC;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return this.cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    // Updated getTemperatureF is no longer a simple getter, but instead a function that derives
    //  its Farenheit value from the Celcius value that actuallyed stored in an instance variable.
    public double getTemperatureF() {
        return this.getTemperatureC() * 9.0/5.0 + 32.0;
    }

    // Updated getTemperatureF is no longer a simple setter, but instead a function
    // that updates the celcius value stored in the instance variable by first converting from Farenheit
    public void setTemperatureF(double temperatureF) {
        this.setTemperatureC((temperatureF - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0);
    }

    // Mew getter, for the new temperatureC instance variable
    public double getTemperatureC() { 
        return this.temperatureC;
    }

    // New setter, for the new temperatureC instance variable
    public void setTemperatureC(double temperatureC) {
        this.temperatureC = temperatureC;
    }
}
```

We've added new getters and setters so that new consumers can deal with temperatures in Celcius. But importantly, we've re-implemented the methods that used to be getters and setters for temperatureF (which no longer exists), to do the appropraite conversions and forward on to the Celcius getters and setters. Because these methods still exist, and behave identically as before, we've successfully made out implementation change (storing F to storing C), *without* breaking our API. Consumers of this API won't notice a difference.

### So why doesn't this translate into Swift?

It does. But simply put, it's already done for you. You see, stored properties in Swift are not instance variables. In fact, Swift *does not provide a way for you to create or directly access instance variables*.

To understand this, we need to have a fuller understanding of what properties are. There are two types, stored and computed, and neither of them are "instance variables".

- Stored properties: Are a combination of a comiler-synthesized instance variable (which you never get to see, hear, touch, taste, or smell), and the getter and setter that you use to interact with them.
- Computed proepties: Are just a getter and setter, without any instance variable to act as backing storage. Really, they just behave as functions with type `() -> T`, and `(T) -> Void`, but have a pleasant dot notation syntax:

  ```
  print(weatherReport.temperatureC)
  weatherReport.temperatureC = 100
  ```

  rather than a function calling synax:

  ```
  print(weatherReport.getTemperatureC())
  weatherReport.setTemperatureC(100)
  ```

So in fact, when you write:

```
class C {
    var i: Int
}
```

`i` is the name of the getter and setter for an instance variable the compiler created for you. Let's call the instance variable `$i` (which is not an otherwise legal Swift identifier). There is no way to directly access `$i`. You can only get its value by calling the getter `i`, or update its value by calling its setter `i`.

So lets see how the `WeatherReport` migration problem looks like in Swift. Our initial type would look like this:

```
public struct WeatherReport {
    public let cityName: String
    public let temperatureF: Double
}
```

Consumers would access the temperature with `weatherReport.temperatureF`. Now, this looks like a direct access of an isntance variable, but remember, that's simply not possible in Swift. Instead, this code calls the compiler-syntehsized getter `temperatureF`, which is what accesses the instance variable `$temperatureF`.

Now let's do our upgrade to Celcius. We will first update our stored property:

```
public struct WeatherReport {
    public let cityName: String
    public let temperatureC: Double
}
```

This has broken our API. New consumers can use `temperatureC`, but old consumers who depended on `temperatureF` will no longer work. To support them, we simply add in a new computed property, that does the conversions between Celcius and Fahenheit:

```
public struct WeatherReport {
    public let cityName: String

    public let temperatureC: Double
    public var temperatureF: Double {
        get { return temperatureC * 9/5 + 32 }
        set { temperatureC = (newValue - 32) * 5/9 }
    }
}
```

Because our `WeatherReport` type still has a getter called `temperatureF`, consumers will behave just as before. They can't tell whether a property that they access is a getter for a stored property, or a computed property that derives its value in some other way.

So lets look at the original "bad" code. What's so bad about it?

```
public class C {
    private var _i: Int = 0
    public var i: Int {
        get {
            return self._i
        }
        set {
            self._i = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `c.i`, the following happens:

1. You access the getter `i`.
2. The getter `i` accesses `self._i`, which is yet another getter
3. The getter `_i` access the "hidden" instance variable `$i`

And it's similar for the setter. You have two layers of "getterness". See what that would look like in Java:

```
public class C {
    private int i;

    public C(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI1() {
        return this.i;
    }

    public void setI1(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI2() {
        return this.getI1();
    }

    public void setI2(int i) {
        this.setI1(i);
    }
}
```

It's silly!

## But what if I want a private setter?

Rather than writing this:

```
public class C {
    private var _i: Int = 0

    public var i: Int {
        get {
            return self._i
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this nifty syntax, to specify a seperate access level for the setter:

```
public class C {
    public private(set) var i: Int = 0
}
```

Now isn't that clean?

Comment: Your properties should be `var` instead of `let` in your `WeatherReport` struct

Comment: @dan Why's that?

Comment: A `let` can't be a computed property, your snippet where you have the `let temperatureF: Double` with the get/set won't compile.

Comment: @Alexander fantastic explanation. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create setters and getters for stored properties in Swift and you shouldn't create them either.

You can control the accessibility of getters/setters separately when you declare a property.

```
public private(set) var name: String // public getter, private setter
```

If you want to implement some custom logic in your setter, you should use property observer, i.e. `didSet`/`willSet`.

```
var name: String {
    didSet {
        // This is called every time `name` is set, so you can do your custom logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will hardly come across the need to create your own getters and setters.
Swift's computed property lets you use getters and setters in a very simple way.

Eg: below defined is a computed property circleArea that returns area of circle depending on radius.

```
var radius: Float = 10

var circleArea: Float {
get {
    return .pi * powf(radius, 2)
}
set {
    radius = sqrtf(newValue / .pi)
}
```

}

While you can observe a stored value and perform some task using property observers:

```
var radius: Float = 10 {
willSet {
    print("before setting the value: \(value)")
}
didSet {
    print("after the value is set: \(value)")
}
```

}

```
radius += 1
```

// before setting the value: 10.0
// after the value is set: 11.0

However if you feel like using getter setter, you can define appropriate functions for that. Below defined is an extension on Integer to get and set properties value.

```
extension Int {
func getValue() -> Int {
    return self
}
mutating func setValue(_ val: Int) {
    self = val
}
```

}

```
var aInt: Int = 29
aInt.getValue()
aInt.setValue(45)
print(aInt)
```

// aInt = 45